# wxDataViewListCtrl display incorrect when not default size

Tags: wxwidgets

Copying the code from the [wxDataViewListCtrl documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_data_view_list_ctrl.html)

```
wxDataViewListCtrl *listctrl = new wxDataViewListCtrl( myPanel, wxID_ANY );
listctrl->AppendToggleColumn( "Toggle" );
listctrl->AppendTextColumn( "Text" );
wxVector<wxVariant> data;
data.push_back( wxVariant(true) );
data.push_back( wxVariant("row 1") );
listctrl->AppendItem( data );
data.clear();data.push_back( wxVariant(false) );
data.push_back( wxVariant("row 3") );
listctrl->AppendItem( data );
```

Produces a reasonable result

[image]

Now I want to make the control bigger and move it slightly down and to the right.  So I change the call to the constructor to

```
wxDataViewListCtrl *listctrl = new wxDataViewListCtrl( myPanel, wxID_ANY
    ,wxPoint(10,10),wxSize(200,100) );
```

The result is the control frame resizes and moves correctly, but the contents vanish

[image]

The is wxWidgets v3.0.0 built with codeblocks and mingw g++

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround:  call setSize after appending items

```
wxDataViewListCtrl *listctrl = new wxDataViewListCtrl( myPanel, wxID_ANY );
... append items ...
 listctrl->SetSize(200,100);
```